# Undefined Offset 0: Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I HAVE already read through the other similar questions on stackoverflow and none of them have helped me to find a solution.

This has be completely confused, what was once working has randomly broken and I have no idea whats wrong, the error doesn't seem logical to me i'll show you what i mean.

```
public function nGetOverviewAccounts()
    {
    $results = Account::where('archive', '=', false)->select('id', 'display_name', 'server_ip_address', 'server_password', 'status_type_id', 'account_type_id')->get()->toArray();

    $index = 0;
    $accounts = [];

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $accountType  = AccountType::where('id', $result['account_type_id'])->select('name')->get()->toArray();
        $statusType   = StatusType::where('id', $result['status_type_id'])->select('name')->get()->toArray();

        return $accountType[0]['name']; //this works

        $accounts[$index]['account_type'] = $accountType[0]['name']; //this doesnt..

        $accounts[$index]['status_type']  = $statusType[0]['name'];

        $index++;
    }

    return $accounts;
}
```

That code is right next to each other in the function. The array `$accountType` looks like this.

```
0:{name: "Google"}
```

Which shows that it has an index of 0 but its not working.

EDIT: PLEASE READ

Im going to clear something up i seems to have put it across wrongly to you guys, the return statement is added by me AFTER i get the undefined index error i only added it to the code to show that it works when i return it but when i try to assign its value to another variable (without the return statement) i get the undefined index error.

Comment: This is the nature of a function handling a return value. Once you return a value, the function "stops" itself, meaning every loop or every code AFTER the first return the functions meets, will not be executed. This is why you only have 1 row instead of n.

Comment: Why are you using the `[0]` anyway. That call looks like it will return only one row anyway so use `$accountType['name']`

Comment: Anyway, as the line you say doesnt work is after a `return` it wont actually ever get executed

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can remove the return statement from the code and it will execute the next line, thats how i've been getting the error in the first place. The return was put their to test the code.

Comment: @Zeratops I think theres a misunderstanding here i dont keep the return in the loop or how else would i have figured out that the next line returns undefined index right? and it only returns 1 row so even without the return statement being there `$accountType[0]['name']` will display that exact same data value

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius use `print_r()` instead of `return` to see the value.

Comment: I'm wondering why you haven't defined the account type and status type relationship using Eloquent and instead you're doing these query chains. It's worth rewriting this bit, it would become a couple of lines of code without any loop.

Comment: @apokryfos its not code that ive written ive been thrown into this project and am trying to add to it, the manager sais its not worth changing whats already there it will be too time consuming so i work with what ive got.

Ive tried to explain but.. clients you know..

Comment: I was using the return statement to try and check the code, to see what was wrong with the statement, it returned what i expected to see but i should have used an "if exists" statement instead.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function nGetOverviewAccounts()
{
$results = Account::where('archive', '=', false)->select('id', 'display_name', 'server_ip_address', 'server_password', 'status_type_id', 'account_type_id')->get()->toArray();

$accounts = [];

foreach($results as $key => $result)
{
    $accountType  = AccountType::where('id', $result['account_type_id'])->select('name')->get()->toArray();
    $statusType   = StatusType::where('id', $result['status_type_id'])->select('name')->get()->toArray();

    if(!empty( $accountType[0]['name'])) && !empty( $statusType[0]['name'])){
    $accounts[$key]['account_type'] = $accountType[0]['name']; //this doesnt..

    $accounts[$key]['status_type']  = $statusType[0]['name']; 
  }
}

return $accounts;
}
```

Also if you want the first key of `$accountType` and `$statusType` then you can use `first()` instead of `get()`. If your keys are different then you can use the `$index`

Comment: The problem isnt with `$results` its with `$accountType[0]`

Comment: In your `foreach` loop you were using `return $accountType[0]['name'];` and hence the value is returned and never pushed inside the array.

Comment: Youve got me wrong im not trying to see whats in the array i already know, i use return to see if it would throw the error still but it doesnt.

When i dont use the return statement the next line below throws an error, that error is "undefined index 0" thats the question im sorry if it came across wrong

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius So in that case, your `$accountsType` variable is returning null. I am updating the code for it.

Comment: Its not returning null, in my question it shows that when i return the variable it gives me the data object i need BUT when im assigning it it sais undefined offset

Comment: in that case provide the ouput for this `print_r($accountType);`

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Google ) ) Array ( )` exactly what it should be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124552/discussion-between-kinshuk-lahiri-and-kenziiee-flavius).

Comment: Thank you the current code helped me figure out the problem.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding some checks never hurt anyone:

```
public function nGetOverviewAccounts() {
    $results = Account::where('archive', '=', false)->select('id', 'display_name', 'server_ip_address', 'server_password', 'status_type_id', 'account_type_id')->get()->toArray();

    $index = 0;
    $accounts = [];

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        $accountType  = AccountType::where('id', $result['account_type_id'])->select('name')->get()->toArray();
        $statusType   = StatusType::where('id', $result['status_type_id'])->select('name')->get()->toArray();


        $accounts[$index]['account_type'] = (isset($accountType[0]) && isset($accountType[0]['name'])?$accountType[0]['name']:"Unknown";

        $accounts[$index]['status_type']  = (isset($statusType[0]) && isset($statusType[0]['name'])?$statusType[0]['name']:"Unknown";

        $index++;
    }

    return $accounts;
}
```

The problem is your "debug" code only checked if it was working for the 1st iteration of the loop, it may still have not been working for the Nth element.

However if this does fix your problem the next question is why are there accounts associated with invalid account type ids. This may be a symptom of a larger problem.

Comment: It was, the reason it was associated with invalid ID's is because the original account type was assigned to multiple accounts. But it was removed from the database but then re-added but with a different ID. Because it uses the ID to check and display data and not the name it was throwing the error, where where you 30 mintues ago!